# Novels with plant based inteligent life forms

Tags: novel, aliens, plants

My question is simple, are there any novels with some sort of intelligent plant race? Better if its a spacefarer race.

For example I remember one placed in earth right before our sun explodes into a nova, a world dominated by plant life forms with a few surviving animal species, including de-evolved humans, ants, bees and cats I think (domesticated by ants). There was some kind of mega spider-plant that webbed from earth to the moon, but it wasn't intelligent.

Comment: Are you looking for examples of works like this or for the specific story described in the second paragraph? The former is off topic but the latter is perfectly fine to ask.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I don't think I have to mention the lethal carrot of The Thing From Another World, do I? If this does not ring a bell, I heartily recommend you watch that film. (But not at night if you are in the North Pole -- way to scary if so.)

Comment: Zhaan was a spacefaring intelligent plant.

Comment: My question was for novels, the second paragraph is just an example... Zhaan and the killer carrots are OK but are from TV series if im not wrong

Comment: There is an intelligent, spacefaring plant race called Skroderiders in Vernor Vinge's *A Fire Upon the Deep*.

Comment: @Opazo In that case then your question is off topic here on SFF as we do not accept recommendation/list questions.

Comment: Since your comment clarifies that you are indeed asking for a list, voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

The story you describe is **Hothouse** by **Brian Aldiss**; it is also known as **The Long Afternoon of Earth**.
It was first published as a short story then expanded into a full (fix-up) novel.